# Python Numpy: Saved array is loaded differently

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to save an array with

```
print myArray.shape, myArray.dtype # returns (yyy, xxx) uint8
numpy.save('savedFile.npy',myArray)
```

and then load it again with

```
myArray = numpy.load('savedFile.npy')
print myArray.shape, myArray.dtype # returns (yyy, ) object
```

How can I get the array in the same shape and dtype as before?

Thank you!

**--- edit ---**

Here is the problem reproduced:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2, os.path

allImageIDs = []
allImages = []
countImagesMax = 20
countImages = 0
while countImages < countImagesMax:
  image = np.uint8(np.random.randint(2, size=(144,192)) *255)
  allImages.append(np.reshape(image, (image.shape[0]*image.shape[1])))
  allImageIDs.append(countImages)
  countImages += 1

myArray = [np.array(allImages), np.array(allImageIDs)]

if not os.path.exists("savedFile.npy"):
  np.save('savedFile.npy',myArray)
  print  myArray[0].shape, myArray[0].dtype # returns (yyy, xxx) uint8
else:
  myArray = np.load('savedFile.npy')
  print  myArray[0].shape, myArray[0].dtype # returns (yyy, ) object
```

Comment: is that supposed to say `numpy.safe` rather than `numpy.save`?  ;-)

Comment: yes, it is... does that help you to provide an answer? :)

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  Can you include a complete, self-contained example that demonstrates the problem?  Something we can just copy and run.  If I save and load a 2D array of type `uint8`, the loaded array has the same shape and type as the array that was saved.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error either... that is really weird... and I am really not doing anything else... when I run the program and generate the data, the shape and dtype are fine. When I run the program again I get the problems.

Comment: TBH, we are unlikely to solve this if even you cannot reproduce the problem. You need to come up with the smallest example that *does* exhibit the issue.

Comment: I understand. I managed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: .. why are you passing a list of arrays to `np.save`?  The documentation says it accepts an array (or array-like object), and recommends using `savez` when you have to save several arrays into a file.  Look at `myArray.shape` itself after you load it.

Comment: @DSM `myArray` could be an acceptable `array_like` if the shape of the two included arrays are the same, but you're right, that isn't the case here and as such the arrays are being stored as object elements of another numpy array rather than being combined into one array of higher dimensionality.

Comment: Thank you everyone helping me out. Using np.savez did the trick. I would upvote your comment or if it was an answer mark it as solution, but through those down-votes I am not able to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discussion in the comments helped me to get to the solution of using `np.savez` instead of `np.save`. Thank you everybody for their comments.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2, os.path

allImageIDs = []
allImages = []
countImagesMax = 20
countImages = 0
while countImages < countImagesMax:
  image = np.uint8(np.random.randint(2, size=(144,192)) *255)
  allImages.append(np.reshape(image, (image.shape[0]*image.shape[1])))
  allImageIDs.append(countImages)
  countImages += 1

myArray = [np.array(allImages), np.array(allImageIDs)]

if not os.path.exists("savedFile.npz"):
  np.savez('savedFile.npz', images=myArray[0], ids=myArray[1])
  print  myArray[0].shape, myArray[0].dtype # returns (yyy, xxx) uint8
else:
  npzfile = np.load('savedFile.npz')
  myArray = [npzfile['images'], npzfile['ids']]
  print  myArray[0].shape, myArray[0].dtype # returns (yyy, xxx) uint8
```